# Android mediarecorder doesn't record data when using libvlc

Tags: android, mediarecorder, libvlc, surface

I want to use the android MediaRecorder to record a remote url. I called a fragment from an acticity with an url, and LibVLC plays that.
I check it's acticvity's onClick event from a Timer task. I want to start recording here. It works, it calls start, but the recording doesn't work.
It creates the output file, but it has a 0 byte - size.

I would be appreciated for any advice.

```
Public class VideoFragment extends Fragment implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, IVideoPlayer {

    public static final String TAG = "VideoFragment";
    public static final String VIDEO_URL = "VIDEO_URL";


    private String mFilePath, ip;
    private SurfaceView mSurface;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private LibVLC libvlc;
    private int mVideoWidth;
    private int mVideoHeight;
    private final static int VideoSizeChanged = -1;
    private Context mContext;
    private EventHandler mEventHandler;
    private ViewGroup mContainer;

    boolean recording;

    MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;

    public static VideoFragment newInstance(String videoURL) {
        VideoFragment fragment = new VideoFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(VIDEO_URL, videoURL);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView");

        View view = View.inflate(
                getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_video, null);

        mContainer = container;
        mContext = getActivity();

        mFilePath = this.getArguments().getString(VIDEO_URL);
        ip = mFilePath.substring(mFilePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, mFilePath.length());
        ip = ip.substring(0, ip.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);


        mSurface = (SurfaceView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_videoview_surface);
        holder = mSurface.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);


        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        initMediaRecorder();

        Timer myTimer = new Timer();

        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Your logic here...

                // When you need to modify a UI element, do so on the UI thread.
                // 'getActivity()' is required as this is being ran from a Fragment.
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // This code will always run on the UI thread, therefore is safe to modify UI elements.
                        if (VideoActivity.startRecord) {
                            VideoActivity.startRecord = false;
                            Log.e("error", "start");
                            mediaRecorder.start();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 2000, 5000);

        return view;
    }
    public void createPlayer() {
        releasePlayer();
        try {
            String media = mFilePath;


            // Create a new media player
            libvlc = new LibVLC();
            mEventHandler = libvlc.getEventHandler();
            libvlc.init(mContext);
            libvlc.setHardwareAcceleration(LibVLC.HW_ACCELERATION_FULL);
            libvlc.setSubtitlesEncoding("");
            libvlc.setAout(LibVLC.AOUT_OPENSLES);
            libvlc.setTimeStretching(true);
            libvlc.setVerboseMode(true);
            libvlc.setNetworkCaching(1000);
            NativeCrashHandler.getInstance().setOnNativeCrashListener(
                    nativecrashListener);
            if (LibVlcUtil.isGingerbreadOrLater())
                libvlc.setVout(LibVLC.VOUT_ANDROID_WINDOW);
            else
                libvlc.setVout(LibVLC.VOUT_ANDROID_SURFACE);
            LibVLC.restartInstance(mContext);
            mEventHandler.addHandler(mHandler);
            holder.setKeepScreenOn(true);
            MediaList list = libvlc.getMediaList();
            list.clear();
            list.add(new Media(libvlc, LibVLC.PathToURI(media)), false);
            libvlc.playIndex(0);
            mute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error creating player!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    /**
     * **********
     * Events
     * ***********
     */

    private Handler mHandler = new MyHandler(this);

    private static class MyHandler extends Handler {
        private WeakReference<VideoFragment> mOwner;

        public MyHandler(VideoFragment owner) {
            mOwner = new WeakReference<VideoFragment>(owner);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            VideoFragment player = mOwner.get();

            // SamplePlayer events
            if (msg.what == VideoSizeChanged) {
                player.setSize(msg.arg1, msg.arg2);
                return;
            }

            // Libvlc events
            Bundle b = msg.getData();
            switch (b.getInt("event")) {
                case EventHandler.MediaPlayerEndReached:
                    player.releasePlayer();
                    break;
                case EventHandler.MediaPlayerPlaying:
                case EventHandler.MediaPlayerPaused:
                case EventHandler.MediaPlayerStopped:
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public OnNativeCrashListener nativecrashListener = new OnNativeCrashListener() {

        @Override
        public void onNativeCrash() {
            Log.e("vlcdebug", "nativecrash");
        }
    };

    public void releasePlayer() {
        if (libvlc == null)
            return;
        mEventHandler.removeHandler(mHandler);
        libvlc.stop();
        libvlc.detachSurface();
        libvlc.closeAout();
        libvlc.destroy();
        libvlc = null;

        mVideoWidth = 0;
        mVideoHeight = 0;
    }

    private void setSize(int width, int height) {
        if (libvlc != null) {
            libvlc.closeAout();
            libvlc.setVolume(0);
        }

        // Dimensions of the native video
        mVideoWidth = width;
        mVideoHeight = height;

        if (mVideoWidth * mVideoHeight <= 1)
            return;

        // Dimensions of the surface frame
        int surfaceFrameW = mContainer.getMeasuredWidth();
        int surfaceFrameH = mContainer.getMeasuredHeight();

        float videoAR = (float) mVideoWidth / (float) mVideoHeight;
        float surfaceFrameAr = (float) surfaceFrameW / (float) surfaceFrameH;

        int vidW = surfaceFrameW;
        int vidH = surfaceFrameH;

        if (surfaceFrameAr < videoAR)
            vidH = (int) (surfaceFrameW / videoAR);
        else
            vidW = (int) (surfaceFrameH * videoAR);

        // force surface buffer size
        if (holder != null) {
            holder.setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Holder was null!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // set display size
        LayoutParams lp = mSurface.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = vidW;
        lp.height = vidH;
        mSurface.setLayoutParams(lp);
        mSurface.invalidate();
    }

    public void mute() {
        libvlc.closeAout();
        libvlc.setVolume(0);
    }

    @Override

    public void onResume() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
        super.onResume();
        createPlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
        super.onPause();
        releasePlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        releasePlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        prepareMediaRecorder();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                               int height) {
        if (libvlc != null)
            libvlc.attachSurface(holder.getSurface(), this);

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void eventHardwareAccelerationError() {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error with hardware acceleration");
        releasePlayer();
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error with hardware acceleration",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSurfaceLayout(int width, int height, int visible_width,
                                 int visible_height, int sar_num, int sar_den) {
        Message msg = Message.obtain(mHandler, VideoSizeChanged, width,
                height);
        msg.sendToTarget();
    }

    // Used only for old stuff
    @Override
    public int configureSurface(Surface surface, int width, int height,
                                int hal) {
        Log.d("", "configureSurface: width = " + width + ", height = "
                + height);
        if (LibVlcUtil.isICSOrLater() || surface == null)
            return -1;
        if (width * height == 0)
            return 0;
        if (hal != 0)
            holder.setFormat(hal);
        holder.setFixedSize(width, height);
        return 1;
    }


    private void initMediaRecorder() {


        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ss");
        String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());


        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String StreamDirectory = settings.getString("StreamDirectory", "");

        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
        CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile_HQ = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
        mediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile_HQ);
        Log.e("error", "itt vagyok");
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(StreamDirectory + "/" + ip + date + "_video.mp4");
        mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(5000); // Set max duration in milisecundum
        mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Set max file size 5M
    }

    private void prepareMediaRecorder() {
        Log.e("error", "prepare");
        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: have you found any solution for it? As i am also working on same thing